# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property:

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to the spring-data-jpa and native query. In this example I want the following sql (shown with the results) to be converted into the JPA Repository Query

```
select c.* from customers c INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city='Nantes';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Afv8.png)

Image with result of query:

So, I did like below -

**CustomerRepository.java**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{
    List<Customer> findByContactFirstName(String firstName);

    @Query("select c from Customer c INNER JOIN Order o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city=:city")
    List<Customer> findByCustomerNumberByCity(@Param("city") String city);
}
```

When I am executing this with the test class

```
@Test
    public void testByCustomerNumber(){
        List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findByCustomerNumberByCity("Nantes");
        System.out.println("Size of Customers : "+customers.size());
    }
```

I see the below error comes.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.scheduler.repository.CustomerRepository.findByCustomerNumberByCity(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.scheduler.repository.CustomerRepository.findByCustomerNumberByCity(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: com.scheduler.model.Order [select c from com.scheduler.model.Customer c INNER JOIN com.scheduler.model.Order o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city=:city]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: com.scheduler.model.Order [select c from com.scheduler.model.Customer c INNER JOIN com.scheduler.model.Order o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city=:city]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
01:39:43.367 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@6500df86 testClass = CustomerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@402a079c testClass = CustomerTest, locations = '{classpath:application-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerNumber;

    private String addressLine1;

    private String addressLine2;

    private String city;

    private String contactFirstName;

    private String contactLastName;

    private String country;

    private double creditLimit;

    private String customerName;

    private String phone;

    private String postalCode;

    private String state;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="salesRepEmployeeNumber")
    private Employee employee;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Order> orders;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Payment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Payment> payments;

    // Assume setters and getters
}
```

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
@NamedQuery(name="Order.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Order o")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int orderNumber;

    @Lob
    private String comments;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date orderDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date requiredDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date shippedDate;

    private String status;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Orderdetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
    private List<Orderdetail> orderdetails;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerNumber")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

**Is this possible to execute such queries using @query repository query ? OR it should be developed using the native sql query ? Please guide.** 
**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
@NamedQuery(name="Order.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Order o")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int orderNumber;

    @Lob
    private String comments;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date orderDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date requiredDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date shippedDate;

    private String status;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Orderdetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
    private List<Orderdetail> orderdetails;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerNumber")
    private Customer customer; 
        // Assume setters and getters present
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see the issue. You need to refactored the `JPA @Query` in the correct way. The following will work fine.

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o WHERE c.customerNumber = 
o.customer.customerNumber AND c.city=:city")
List<Customer> findByCustomerNumberByCity(@Param("city") String city);
```

Are you using mysql schema from link : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx .If yes then the following test case yield the result:

```
@Test
public void testfindByCustomerNumberByCityJPA(){
    List<Customer> customers = custmerRepository.findByCustomerNumberByCity("Nantes");
    System.out.println("Size of Customers : "+customers.size());
}
```

To answer highlighted parts:

1) `JPA repository` query will not be good option if you're doing complex join works. If you're doing couple of joins then `JPA repository` query is good option.

2) If you're working with complex joins with many tables, then its advisable to use `EntityManager` and create a Native Query like this `Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());` where sql will be your native query.

Hope this will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: com.scheduler.model.Order [select c from com.scheduler.model.Customer c INNER JOIN com.scheduler.model.Order o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city=:city]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: customerNumber of: com.scheduler.model.Order [select c from com.scheduler.model.Customer c INNER JOIN com.scheduler.model.Order o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city=:city]
```

Attribute customerNumber is not exposed in Domain Order. 
Hence hibernate not able to execute below query

> select c from com.scheduler.model.Customer c INNER JOIN com.scheduler.model.Order o ON c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber where c.city=:city